# My minecraft isn't giving me my blocks as soon as I mine them

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just recently got Minecraft and I realized that as soon as I break a block it takes almost 4 to 7 seconds or more to give me my block. Is this a normal glitch for update 1.7.4? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could be you lagging.

Comment: What blocks are you trying to break? Are you using the appropriate tool for it?

Comment: @CédricDereme Did you read the WHOLE question?

Comment: Are you playing singleplayer or multiplayer?

Comment: Sounds like you're lagging on a multiplayer server. More information would be useful.

Comment: Continuing on what @Bryan said, lag on block break may be related to the server you're on (assuming you're on multiplayer). I recently had a similar issue on my server, about 1 second after block break to give the block.  In my case, my server's cpu was pegged at 100% during this time. I scaled up to a bigger machine, and the problem has gone away.  There could be other causes for this, I'm just pointing out what it was for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find out, how much memory is consumed by the time you're breaking a block.

The shortcut for it is **Shift+F3**.

You might also see an increase in the memory at the top right corner, where the percentage of used memory is showed.

Last but not least, try to watch the FPS count in the top left corner in the first line.
This might as well drop.

All in all, i guess you either have too little memory for Minecraft or you had a lot of other programs open at that time.

*TL;DR:* **F3** / **Shift+F3** should give you some tips about the memory consumption at the time, where you break a block.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It's lag. When you mine or collect a block it appears on the ground for about 1.24 seconds (sometimes longer if you have tremendous lag). Lowering your GUI settings and CPU consumption will allow you to collect materials with ease.